# how to change td content after ajax update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to update the content of my td which have unique id after an ajax update.

However my approach doesnt work, the ajax is succesful but td will only update after page reload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').on('click', '.editButton', function(e){

            var postID = $(this).val();
            var postURL = "../Controller/update.php";
            var postNama = $("#nama"+postID).val();
            var postMSISDN = $("#msisdn"+postID).val();
            var postSMS = $("#sms"+postID).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: postURL,
                data:
                {
                    nama: postNama,
                    msisdn: postMSISDN,
                    sms: postSMS,
                    id: postID
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#nama"+postID).html(postNama);
                    $("#msisdn"+postID).html(postMSISDN);
                    $("#sms"+postID).html(postSMS);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

the html i echoed :

```
                            <tr id='tr".$data['id']."'>
                            <td>".$data['id']."</td>
                            <td id='nama".$data['id']."'>".$data['nama']."</td>
                            <td id='msisdn".$data['id']."'>".$data['msisdn']."</td>
                            <td id='sms".$data['id']."'>".$data['sms']."</td>
                            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal".$data['id']."'>Edit</button></td>
                            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal".$data['id']."'>Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
```

update.php :

```
<?php
require_once "../Model/Model.php";

$nama = $_POST["nama"];
$msisdn = $_POST["msisdn"];
$sms = $_POST["sms"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

updateData($nama, $msisdn, $sms, $id);
?>
```

model.php :

```
    function updateData($nama, $msisdn, $sms, $id){
    try{
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=crud', 'root', '');

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn->prepare("UPDATE data SET nama = ?, msisdn = ?, sms = ? WHERE id = ?")->execute([$nama, $msisdn, $sms, $id]);
}
```

Comment: can you show the html ?

Comment: i have edited my post @ShaktiPhartiyal

Comment: Do you wan the data returned from the server to be applied on your ids ? and if so is the data returning from the server a JSON ?

Comment: yes, i want to replace my <td> content with the one returned from the server, and its not JSON, i havent learned that yet.

Comment: Ok so what does your server return exactly ?

Comment: here http://imgur.com/a/9Fw5W , i tried to edit my name and it succeed, now i want to refresh my table with the new data

Comment: Please show the responses tab not the headers tab..

Comment: sorry, theres nothing in the responses tab

Comment: Well that means the server is returning nothing.. try echoing out json like I said in my answer to see the result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I think the problem is that you are using the same id for inputs you are taking the data from and the element you are trying to fill the data in. So you just need to change the ids for the td elements and edit the script according to that. Like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.editButton', function(e){

        var postID = $(this).val();
        var postURL = "../Controller/update.php";
        var postNama = $("#nama"+postID).val(); //there are ids of the inputs
        var postMSISDN = $("#msisdn"+postID).val();
        var postSMS = $("#sms"+postID).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: postURL,
            data:
            {
                nama: postNama,
                msisdn: postMSISDN,
                sms: postSMS,
                id: postID
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#nama-td-"+postID).html(postNama); //and there for the td elements
                $("#msisdn-td-"+postID).html(postMSISDN);
                $("#sms-td-"+postID).html(postSMS);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

And of course change the html according to that:

```
                        <td id='nama-td-".$data['id']."'>".$data['nama']."</td>
                        <td id='msisdn-td-".$data['id']."'>".$data['msisdn']."</td>
                        <td id='sms-td-".$data['id']."'>".$data['sms']."</td>
```

I also would recommend you to check on the server if there is no error saving the data print the error and donnt change the values if there was.

Comment: this isnt working, i have added the html, could you please look at it ?

Comment: The HTML is ok i woud rather see the server response for the ajax call.

Comment: here http://imgur.com/a/9Fw5W
i tried to edit my name and it succed, i just want to refresh my table to match the new data.

Comment: sorry, theres nothing in response tab.

Comment: So your server script only saves the data and returns nothing? Or what it does? I am not sure what you are trying to do. You take data from the td element send it to the server and than you return the same data to the td element. So no wonder nothing changes. There should be some input involved..or how do you change the data before sending it to the server? Could you please describe what you are trying to achive in more detail.

Comment: i want to update the data with bootstrap modal, and upon clicking save, i do an ajax call to update whatever data i changed in the modal to database, and then i want to refresh my tabel with that new data.

Comment: @jsnalf I have updated my answer check it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: hello, your code didnt help me, but your statement that im using same id do, turned out that i have same ID in my modal and my table. 

thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to pass return data in the td like this,as the data paramter is used to send the data to the server.

```
success: function(data){
   $("#nama"+postID).html(data);
   $("#msisdn"+postID).html(data);
   $("#sms"+postID).html(data);
 }
```

Comment: not working, i have added the html. could you please look at it ?

Comment: can you please show me how you are returning the data from the function ?

Answer (score 0):

If your server returns a JSON then you can use the following technique:

Let us assume your serve returns JSON data like so:

```
{name:"somename",msisdn:"9898989898",sms:"some_sms"}
```

Then you can apply the following:

```
success: function(data){
$("#nama"+postID).html(data.name);
$("#msisdn"+postID).html(data.msisdn);
$("#sms"+postID).html(data.sms);
}
```

Remember if your server does not send the content type :`application/json` headers with the data then you need to parse the response first like so:

```
success: function(data){
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
$("#nama"+postID).html(parsedData.name);
$("#msisdn"+postID).html(parsedData.msisdn);
$("#sms"+postID).html(parsedData.postSMS);
}
```